# How to pass the widget as a parameter to the function

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to pass some widgets as a parameter to function, does flutter support that? Below is my code. Should I pass a widget as a parameter to function?

This is the widget that I want to pass as a parameter:

```dart
class FirstWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return Container(
            child: Text('i am the first'),
        );
    }
}
class SecondWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return Container(
            child: Text('i am the second'),

        );
    }
}
```

`createWidget` is the important:

```dart
class Main extends StatelessWidget {
    // maybe return a widget i wanna, maybe return a default widget.
    Widget _createWidget(widget){
        // do something to judge
        if(dosomething){
           return Container(
               child: Text('nothing'),
           );
        }
        // i wanna `widget()` at this postion. not when `_createWidget`
        return widget();
    }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                _createWidget(FirstWidget),
                _createWidget(SecondWidget),
            ],
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass an *instance* of the `Widget` to your function and then return it:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
        _createWidget(FirstWidget()),
        _createWidget(SecondWidget()),
    ],
  );
}

Widget _createWidget(Widget widget) {
  // ... other stuff...
  return widget;
}
```

Or if you want to defer constructing `FirstWidget()` and `SecondWidget()` until *after* you've called `_createWidget()` (for example, if you want `_createWidget` to return the constructed widget conditionally), you could use an anonymous function to create a [*thunk*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
        _createWidget(() => FirstWidget()),
        _createWidget(() => SecondWidget()),
    ],
  );
}

Widget _createWidget(Widget Function() widgetBuilder) {
  // ... other stuff...
  return widgetBuilder();
}
```

Comment: thanks! defer constructing `FirstWidget()` and `SecondWidget()` until after i called _createWidget() is what i really want. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass anything to a function.
Change your function definition as follow:

```dart
    Widget _createWidget(Widget child){
        // do something to judge
        if(dosomething){
           return Container(
               child: Text('nothing'),
           );
        }
        // Notice that you just return the variable and not call it as a function.
        // return child(); <-- this one will result in an error
        return child; // <-- this is the right way
    }
```